# Dynamically save data from form into array and displayed this

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p><label for="id_book">Book:</label> <select id="id_book" name="book">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="5">2</option>
<option value="10">3</option>
</select></p>

<p><label for="id_category">Category:</label> <select id="id_category" name="category">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="5">2</option>
<option value="7">4</option>
</select></p>

<p><label for="id_pages">Pages:</label> <input id="id_pages" name="pages" type="number"/></p>

<button type="button">Add</button>
```

I have these fields. How can I after click on `Add` button save all data from my form into for example array and display it? I need have possibility to filling this form many times. At the end I need to save these datas in backend script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should consider to at least use some library like [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) which has a wonderful data model api.

However, using pure jquery, this could look like:

http://jsbin.com/noxarufu/1/edit

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var values = {
      book: '',
      category: '',
      pages: 0
    };

    function onAdd() {
      values.book = $('#id_book').val();
      values.category = $('#id_category').val();
      values.pages = $('#id_pages').val();

      console.log(values)
    }
  </script>
```

Open console to view results.

To add a *new row* of values for each click:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var values = [];

    function onAdd() {
      var addVal = {
        book: $('#id_book').val(),
        category: $('#id_category').val(),
        pages: $('#id_pages').val()
      }
      values.push(addVal);

      console.log(values)
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks you. Can I dynamicly create variable with JSON format like this: https://dpaste.de/dkVA (after every click extend this with new item)?

Comment: sure. just add a new object for each click to an array!